# Updating my website/ web hosting?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-deployment

I'm new to web design and website deployment. I had some general questions that I tried to research but failed. I know how to use `Html/CSS/Javascript` and I managed to design my own website and upload it and host it using `Amazon s3` / `Route 53`. It's a website built from scratch with `HTML`, `CSS`.

The thing that I have failed to understand is managing the website after deployment. Do I simply add `HTML` pages to my amazon bucket whenever I want to update? is this the way to do it? I came across `jekyll` in my research and from what I understood, it's a static website generator. But does it help with organizing the website and facilitating adding more content after deployment?

in other words, how do developers go about managing their websites generally after deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I simply add HTML pages to my amazon bucket whenever I want to update? is this the way to do it?

**Yes**. The simplest way is to make changes to your files in your local workspace and then upload/overwrite the changed files to the S3 storage.

> But does [jekyll] help with organizing the website and facilitating adding more content after deployment?

**Yes**! Jekyll is a great way to organise and generate your *static site* and I highly recommend it if you are planning to continue creating and deploying content to your site.

Start here, but note that it's a little more difficult if you're on Windows OS.
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/#requirements

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the Amazon s3 or jekyll etc. How I manage my sites is I use a hosting provider that provides Plesk. With Plesk I manage all my files for my sites in the file manager and I can even edit the code in the online code editor provided. It also has built in apps like Joomla and Wordpress.

I can set up email addresses for each site and also subdomains. Security etc.

When I want to update or edit my site I will either do it in the online code editor if it is something small like changing a color or just a few lines of code. Otherwise for bigger edits I will do it all on my desktop using notepad and then upload all the new files and replace the existing ones.

Each domain has it's own folder in the directory so it is easy to maintain and things don't get messy.

I hope this helps. You said you want to know how developers manage their sites. Although I am not a professional developer, I do have a few sites and that is how I manage them.

It only costs £40 per year too so is quite cheap.